# Complex statements in the member initialization part?

Tags: c++, member-initialization

I have this:

```
struct myClass{
    multiset<string,binPred<string> > values ;

    myClass(const char param1, const char param2) : values(less<string>())
    { }
} ;
```

I need to initialize the **`values`** member with a different functor depending on the values of **`param1`** and **`param2`**. Unfortunately, the logic to decide which functor to use is not so simple and once **`values`** is constructed I cant change its associated comparison functor.

So... I would need to put all that decision logic in the member initializaion part, but I dont know how aside using the **`?:`** operator.
Is it possible to put more complex statements in there?? (like `switch` staments)

If not, is there a way to delay the construction of **`values`** so I can initialize it in the constructor's body??

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a static member function that will accept the parameters you have and return a necessary value. This solves the problem completely and allows for clean easily debuggable code.

Answer (score 9):

Call a function:

```
myClass(const char param1, const char param2) 
             : values( MakeComplicatedDecision( xxx ) ) {
}
```

and put your logic in the function.

Comment: Which should have no requirement on the attributes of the class as they are yet to be initialized.

Comment: IMHO, it should not be possible to call non-static member functions here, but unfortunately it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a pointer to a multiset for values, then use `new` to create it in the constructor. This would delay construction, but it does mean a small amount of overhead.